# How can I configure Contact Us form & Contact Email in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.4, contact-us

Please explain Simple ways to configure the Contact Us form and Contact Email.

How can I Enable the Contact Us Form?

How to Customize the Email Contact form ?

How to Configure the Contact Us form?

Comment: Try this link

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/contact-us.html

And

https://amasty.com/blog/customize-contact-us-form-in-magento-2/

Comment: use can customize and configure contact us form email template from `marketing->communication->email templates->select contact us email template`